# Exec Task in MSBuild for execution of command on remote machine

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, execcommand

I am using following command to install a service via MSBuild file. This works great

```
 <Exec Command= 'c:\test\myService.Appservices.exe install' ContinueOnError='false' />
```

But the above command install the service on local machine. I want to install the service on a remote machine. How can I specify the machine name using this command?

Comment: This isn't really an msbuild question. AFAIK msbuild has no built in support for remote machine installation, it can just execute commands. When you know which command to execute, msbuild can take over from there. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995050/install-software-on-a-remote-machine may point you in the right direction. Alternatively edit your tags to include things like 'remote-access' to get a broader coverage.

Answer (score 5):

As per Mike Vine's comment, MSBuild doesn't include tools for remote execution. You could however use something like [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). e.g.

```
<Exec Command='psexec -accepteula -s \\RemoteServer "C:\Path To EXE on Remote Machine\my.EXE"' IgnoreExitCode="false" ContinueOnError="false" Timeout="600000" >
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="exitCode1"/>
</Exec>
```

Comment: Why do you use the -s parameter? Did cost us an hour : p

Comment: Another advice: Do not put arguments of the application inside the double quotes of the path.

Comment: -s runs psexec as "system" on the remote machine, without that flag it runs as the account that msbuild is ruining under