# Installing msi via a batch file to a remote computer

Tags: batch-file, psexec, windows-installer

I am working on a batch file that includes some tools for my local helpdesk guys to use.  I am currently working on one of the tools which is to transfer and install Cisco AnyConnect for VPN usage on workstations.  I was able to get the copy/transfer of the installer files down but cannot for the life of me figure out how to launch the .msi installer that is now on the remote computer.  I am not very familiar with this portion of .bat files so any help would be appreciated.

*Note: I want to use a batch file for right now, at some point I will develop a desktop application for my tool but this is time sensitive.

*EDIT* I have been able to obtain and get PSEXEC put onto my computer so that could be an option as well.  I have looked around online but really can only find help if just installing the software by itself.  I know that it works in conjunction with msiexec.

I have the following but know I need more:
psexsec \%id%\c$ cmd /c "c:\temp\vpn install"
msiexec /i anyconnect-win-4.7.04056-core-vpn-predeploy-k9.msi /quiet /norestart

How would I call out the msi to be installed and install it in the process?

TIA

Comment: Got to a new point:
c:\temp\psexec.exe "\\%id%\c$\temp\vpn install" -d -s cmd /c msiexec.exe /I anyconnect-win-4.7.04056-core-vpn-predeploy-k9.msi /quiet /norestart

Now getting a new error that it cannot access the remote computer path.  Is this maybe a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

> ***Silence!***: [Installing silently using msiexec.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55476766/129130)

---

***VBScript***: I haven't tested this to be honest, but there is this sample here: [Install Software on a Remote Computer](https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/apps/user/scr_217.asp) (using VBScript). It seems to be the same script as on [TechNet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4a4a6e09-8031-4a3e-b081-1d7cbb9cde9c). I am used to distribution systems such as SCCM and the likes - hence no testing of this.

***Options***: You can use Active Directory to deploy "well-designed" MSI files using [Group Policy Objects](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-gpo.html). I don't use this approach - again: no test environment. And there are logon scripts that can kick off installs from UNC paths (like the one above) and there are scheduled tasks - which can do the same.

***Active Directory / GPO***:

- [How to use Group Policy to remotely install software in Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816102/how-to-use-group-policy-to-remotely-install-software-in-windows-server)
- [How to assign software to a specific group by using Group Policy in Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/324750/how-to-assign-software-to-a-specific-group-by-using-group-policy-in-wi)

***Some Links***: (for easy retrieval)

- [Install software on a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995050/install-software-on-a-remote-machine)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/25724/install-software-on-a-remote-machine
- https://superuser.com/questions/970691/how-can-i-use-psexec-to-install-software-on-a-remote-computer
- https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way
- [Installing .msi remotely without powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880264/installing-msi-remotely-without-powershell)

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions.  Unfortunately, I am in an evironment that really restricts alteration of current GPO's and our ability to run advanced scripts are limited, thus the use of a batch file as that seems to be my work around.  I will look into your information however and see what I can build from that.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So after a couple days of messing around with the scripting and way more google searches than I wanted to do, I finally got it to work.  I ended up using the following

WMIC /Node:ComputerName process call create 'msiexec.exe /i \computername\path

This installed it without any error.

Comment: [Forgot to add a link to this - Powershell across the wire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file/46637095#46637095). Not spot on, but just for reference.